# template webform submission page

Tags: drupal, webforms, theming

I'm new to drupal and theming and I want to design the following page for webform submission.
`webform/my_form/submissions`
Is there a file I should override in my theme?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I set the debug to true in services.yml file to check the names of the files. I found
`<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/dataset/table.html.twig' -->`
then I override it in my theme.